# actionListner not triggering for MenuItem for a programatically created ContextMenu for pogramatically created UIComponents

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, contextmenu, menuitem

I now really need your help. I have spent now almost a week to crack this problem, but no success.

I am using PrimeFaces and I have a situation where I need to create a dynamic form with dynamic UIComponents. This work fine for me.

Next, for these dynamically created UIComponents, I need to show a dynamic context menus. This also works fine for me, but when I click the MenuItems, my actionListener is not getting triggered.

Here's how my code looks like:

```
private void addContextMenu(Panel panel, ......){
    ...................
    Submenu submenu;
    MenuItem menuItem;

    Application application = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
    ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = application.getExpressionFactory();
    ContextMenu contextMenu = (ContextMenu) application.createComponent(ContextMenu.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    contextMenu.setStyleClass("applyBG");
    contextMenu.setFor(panel.getId());        
    contextMenu.setId("CM_"+panel.getId().substring(3));

..................
..................

    //Add SubMenus for Parent TableContainerElements
    do{
        submenu = (Submenu) application.createComponent(Submenu.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        submenu.setLabel(..........);
        submenu.setId(........);

        menuItem = (MenuItem) application.createComponent(MenuItem.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        menuItem.setId(.......);
        menuItem.setValue(......);
        menuItem.addActionListener(
                new MethodExpressionActionListener(expressionFactory.createMethodExpression(
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), 
                "#{testManagedBean.checkTestCommand}", null, new Class[] { ActionEvent.class })));
        submenu.getChildren().add(menuItem);

        <.......Add one more MenuItem to subMenu......>


        contextMenu.getChildren().add(submenu);
    }while(...........);

    panel.getChildren().add(contextMenu);
}
```

Here's how my ActionListener looks like:

```
public void checkTestCommand(ActionEvent ae){
    System.err.println("Test Command Received");
    MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)ae.getSource();
    System.err.println(menuItem.getId());
    ContextMenu contextMenu = (ContextMenu)menuItem.getParent();
    System.err.println(contextMenu.getId());
}
```

Please suggest me what's going wrong here. I would be really grateful.

Thanks and best regards,
Anand.

Comment: How does the generated submenu look like in xhtml?

Comment: Where can I find generated submenu xhtml? I am creating it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem in your code. anonymous inner class not working for addactionlistener property.do this i hope it'll help you.

```
menuItem.addActionListenr(new classname);

//create class implements actionlistener interface

classname implements ActionListenr{

    privide your code
}
```